# Reference for coercive property

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, coercive

**Problem:** Let $X$ be a Banach space and $H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $A$ be a linear continuous operator from $X$ to $H$. Here, we say that $A$ is coercive if there exists real number $c>0$ such that
$$|| Ax||_H\geq c||x||_X, \hspace{0.5cm} \forall x\in X.$$
My question is under what condition, above coercivity holds?

**Special case:** Let us assume that $X=\mathbb R^n$ and $H=\mathbb R^m$ and $A$ is a matrix of size $m\times n$. If the symmetric matrix $A^TA$ is non-singular then we can choose $c=\lambda_1>0$ where $\lambda_1$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

Comment: This is equivalent to $A$ being injective and range of $A$ is closed. There should be already questions about this on this site

Comment: @daw Many thanks for your comment. It seems to be easy to prove that if $A$ is coercive then $A$ is injective. But, I don't understand why we have the remaining/equivalence. The link you suggested is not clear to me, for example, they work on Hilbert and orthogonal spaces, which are not well defined in Banach spaces. Could you please post a concrete answer, or, a little bit more detailed comment is really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: this is more on point: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523730/show-that-t-is-injective-and-has-closed-range-iff-exists-c-0-forall - it should help you to get a start for searching ;)

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the problem I need. I really appreciate your help. Thank you!